# Use custom scrapy imagePipeline to download images and overwrite existing images

Tags: python, scrapy

I am practising using scrapy to crop image with a custom imagePipeline. 
I am using this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630397/scrapy-convert-image):

```
class MyImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):

def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
    for image_url in item['image_urls']:
        yield Request(image_url)

def convert_image(self, image, size=None):
    if image.format == 'PNG' and image.mode == 'RGBA':
        background = Image.new('RGBA', image.size, (255, 255, 255))
        background.paste(image, image)
        image = background.convert('RGB')
    elif image.mode != 'RGB':
        image = image.convert('RGB')

    if size:
        image = image.copy()
        image.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    else:
        #  cut water image  TODO use defined image replace Not cut 
        x,y = image.size
        if(y>120):
            image = image.crop((0,0,x,y-25))

    buf = StringIO()
    try:
        image.save(buf, 'JPEG')
    except Exception, ex:
        raise ImageException("Cannot process image. Error: %s" % ex)

    return image, buf
```

It works well but have a problem.
If there are original images in the folder,
then run the spider,
the images it download won't replace the original one.

How can I get it to over-write the original images ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [expiration setting](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/images.html#image-expiration), it is by default 90 days.